# how to generate a marker for each value in a table (google maps API v3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Basically I need to run a function for every value in a table. Maybe some loop or something? I'm new to jQuery and javascript. I want to display a marker on the map canvas for each latlng I have stored in my table. How do I do this?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

What you want to get is an array of objects that contain the latitude and longitude of the marker, then you can loop over the array of objects and add the markers to the map. You may also want your map to zoom to fit the markers. This is referred to in the [Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) as "bounds". [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5szkjy5b/)

```
var map;
var mapOptions = {
    center: {lat: 51.5048835, lng: 0.1101221},
    zoom: 12
};
var markers = [
    {lat: 51.5048835, lng: -0.1101221},
    {lat: 51.5053532, lng: -0.1085023,},
    {lat: 51.5072948, lng: -0.103489}
];

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    addMarkers();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function addMarkers() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng);
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
        });

        bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but my latlngs are stored in a table and not under "var markers"

Comment: @Mr.Liam You will need to output your markers from your database table as json. What database and back-end language are you using?

Comment: I'm stringifying the coordinates through json. I would put the db query inside of var markers?

Comment: @Mr.Liam You would put your json in the markers array and format it as you need. Can you provide a sample of the data you are using?